# SignalR removes connection ID's from server

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

when I wrote server for game I got problem:

SignalR hub (with MessagePack) removes connection ID and then disconnects client.
Any Timeout options (in `.AddSignalR`) & Nginx headers doesn't help.

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. This doesn't describe the problem.